# How do I debug XML calls to my ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api

I'm building a simple ASP.NET Web API to receive and post simple data transfer objects (DTO).

```
public TestDTO Get()
{
  return new TestDTO();
}

public void Post([FromBody]TestDTO value)
{
  var test = value.ToEntity();
}
```

The TestDTO contains one method `ToEntity()`, which translates the DTO to an Entity object.

I first do a GET request to get an example DTO, and then POST it back to the service. When I specify `Content-Type: application/json` in the request headers, everything works fine.

But when I specify `Content-Type: application/xml`, I `GET` an example TestDTO fine, but nothing I've tried allows the `POST` to work. I just get an exception that complains that `value` is null when it tries to call `ToEntity()`.

When I try to debug the statement to see why it won't parse the XML, the call stack just contains a reference to `[External Code]`.

My question is, how do I debug the `POST` function so I can find out why it won't parse the XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Potential Issue:**
One case where this will happen is if you are using fields rather than properties for your DTO. In that case you will need to decorate the class with `[DataContract]` and the fields with `[DataMember]`

For more info: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#xml_media_type_formatter.

### How to debug

If you want to debug into Web API code, you can use source packages from symbolsource.org
https://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Wiki/Using

#### Configuring Visual Studio

To configure Visual Studio for symbol/server use, follow these instructions:

1. Go to Tools -> Options -> Debugger -> General.
2. Uncheck “Enable Just My Code (Managed only)”.
3. Uncheck “Enable .NET Framework source stepping”. Yes, it is misleading, but if you don't, then Visual Studio will ignore your custom server order (see further on) and only use it's own servers.
4. Check “Enable source server support”.
5. Uncheck “Require source files to exactly match the original version”
6. Go to Tools -> Options -> Debugger -> Symbols.
7. Select a folder for the local symbol/source cache. You may experience silent failures in getting symbols if it doesn't exist or is read-only for some reason.
8. Add symbol servers under “Symbol file (.pdb) locations”. Pay attention to the correct order, because some servers may contain symbols for the same binaries: with or without sources. We recommend the following setup:

   - http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols
   - http://srv.symbolsource.org/pdb/Public or the authenticated variant (see above)
   - http://srv.symbolsource.org/pdb/MyGet or the authenticated variant (see above)
   - (other symbol servers with sources)
   - http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
   - (other symbol servers without sources)

You can alternatively build & compile yourself as Web API is open sourced
http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

Answer (score 0):

What works for situations like this is to put a proxy between your browser and your server and watch what is happening. Hardcore use use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), but I find that for HTTP debugging a bit of an overkill. Off my head I know 3 options:

- [CharlesProxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) (all platforms)
- [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) (Windows)
- [TCPMon](http://ws.apache.org/tcpmon/) (all platforms, abandoned)

Typically you would add the proxy on your dev machine, but I also had success to put it on the server (e.g. listening on port 81 to redirect to 80).

Comment: I use both Fiddler and Wireshark - I know what I'm sending to the C# application. My problem is that the C# app is not correctly parsing the XML that I'm sending through, and I can't find out *why*. There are no informative exceptions, and I can't check the call stack, even on a Debug build.